# Using NetLink to Import Excel File

Tags: import, excel, .netlink

I can import an Excel file into Mathematica easily:

[image]

But when I try from .Net it fails:

[image]

---

These are the commands and errors I am getting:

```
xlData = Import[\"C://Users//138013//Desktop//RefinedDataset.xlsx\", {\"Sheets\", \"MySheet\"}]
```

> "Import::chtype: \r\n   First argument
>   C://Users//138013//Desktop//RefinedDataset.xlsx\r\n     is not a valid
>   file, directory, or URL specification."

```
xlData = Import[\"//Desktop//RefinedDataset.xlsx\", {\"Sheets\", \"MySheet\"}]
```

> "Import::nffil: File not found during Import."

---

I've done research and seen these articles but nothing shed light on why its an invalid file:

<sub>[Importing from Excel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3420/importing-from-excel)

[Open Excel file with Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4594/open-excel-file-with-mathematica)

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/XLS.html</sub>

---

Does someone know why `Import` is giving me a **is not a valid file** when the same command works in Mathematica and the file does exist and is valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answering my own question to help future .Net/Mathematica Developers. I've posted this answer as a Community Wiki, if anyone has a better/alternate solution please share.*

This Q & A helped : [How to set path of IMPORT from excel into Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16223/how-to-set-path-of-import-from-excel-into-mathematica) but is specific to Mathematica - which works for me although same command via .NetLink fails.

It turns out **in .Net you have to use 4 slashes**:

[image]